# No result is being saved but the result are fetched on the table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this list that is passed from the controller to the view but No result is being saved when i tried saving it, what can be wrong  ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8FJz.jpg)
 
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
                     @for (var i = 0; i < Model.IndicatorDetails.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].FacilityID
                                    <input name=" @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].FacilityID" value=" @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].FacilityID" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].valueMeasured
                                    <input name=" @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].valueMeasured" value=" @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].valueMeasured" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].Month
                                    <input name=" @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].Month" value=" @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].Month" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].Year
                                    <input name=" @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].Year" value=" @Model.IndicatorDetails[i].Year" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />

                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Reset
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

PostAverageWaitTime Method, This is the method that is being used to save the form but when i debug to check what is in "PillarAndIndicatorViewModels", the result is 0 but what was fetched is more t

```
public ActionResult PostAverageWaitTime(PillarAndIndicatorViewModel PillarAndIndicatorViewModels)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime EncodedDate = DateTime.Today;
            foreach (var IndicatorDet in PillarAndIndicatorViewModels.IndicatorDetails)
            {

                IndicatorDetail ID = new IndicatorDetail
                {
                    StrategyPillarID = IndicatorDet.StrategyPillarID,
                    IndicatorID = IndicatorDet.IndicatorID,
                    FacilityID = IndicatorDet.FacilityID,
                    valueMeasured = IndicatorDet.valueMeasured,
                    valueMeasurement = IndicatorDet.valueMeasurement,
                    EncodedDate = EncodedDate,
                    active = IndicatorDet.active,
                    OPIP = IndicatorDet.OPIP,
                    Month = IndicatorDet.Month,
                    Year = IndicatorDet.Year
                };
                db.IndicatorDetails.Add(ID);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            TempData["Success"] = "Details Added Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Indicatordetail");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string exp = ex.ToString();
        }
            return View();
    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to show us the controller code and how you're saving it, this isn't enough to debug.

Comment: @Train i have edited it to add the controller code

Comment: @KehindeOgundeyi You will need to set entity state as added, then only EF (assuming you are using EF) knows you are creating new entity.  Also, on a side but related note, you could move saveChanges out of for loop as DBContext works as transaction.

Comment: @sam i have done that but still the same

Comment: @KehindeOgundeyi Could you update the post with what you have done and also, I assume you are getting collection from view to your PostAverageWaitTime. Is that correct?

Comment: @sam alright.. yes, that's correct

Comment: @sam i have updated the post with what i have done, i used the for loop instead of foreach loop but still no data is being saved

Comment: @KehindeOgundeyi Could you tell us whether db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled is true or false in your case. If its false, then Add won't be treated as new entity.

Comment: @sam yes it is true

Comment: @KehindeOgundeyi Then I don't see anything wrong here. Please post your complete view (entire form) including form tag .

Answer (score 0):

The object ID is never populated, so you are adding an object that is null.
Try adding a breakpoint and follow the foreach in your controller and see what happens

Comment: yes i have added the breakpoint and i know it is never populated but i will like to know why it is never populated because from the view, it has values